# XPath to click toggle button in web table

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, testing, xpath

While trying to automate my application, one of the web-page has a toggle button inside a table and I need to select the same. Below is the image of HTML code.I am unable to copy paste the code hence attaching the image.

[image]

Below is the code tried but getting error as unable to locate element.

```cs
IWebElement btn3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='livingExpenseConsent']/ancestor::span"));
Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
action2.MoveToElement(btn3).Click().Perform();
```

Kindly suggest the right way to locate the element.

Comment: It would be better if you provide html code instead of an image. BTW the `span` with the slider is not an ancestor. May be is a `following-sibling` but I don't know if Selenium supports that.

Comment: Could you not simply set your xpath to click on the input element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ancestor` is generally used to search for parent elements or greater. If it is the `span` element that you are wanting to set your XPath as then using `following-sibling` should work. This looks at all the elements on the same level as the element being used to search for `following-sibling`'s. In your case the `input` element.

XPath:
`//input[@id='livingExpenseConsent']/following-sibling::span`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below xpath.

```
//input[@id='livingExpenseConsent']/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: Please accept the answer for the benefit of future readers.